# nodejs server is not responding after a while

Tags: ubuntu, node.js, vmware-player

I've running a Ubuntu Server guest on my Windows Host (using VMware Player).
My nodejs app starts with a upstart-forever script:

```
description "My App"

start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up IFACE=eth0)
stop on shutdown

respawn
respawn limit 10 5

expect fork

script
    cd /myApp/folder
    exec forever app.js
end script
```

The app starts as expected but after a while (2 - 5 hours) the server is not responding.
If i connect with ssh to the linux server, the server is responding again.

I tried to turn off acpi, but it doesn't change something

```
/etc/default/grub

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi=off"
```

Has anyone the same problem especially with ubuntu + vmware?